# Javascript can't work because of hypen

Tags: javascript

From my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fredang85/GxVFH/)

```
<select id="doesnt-work">
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option value="111">Pineapple</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<input type="textbox" id="mytextbox"/>
<button onclick="displayResult(doesnt-work)">Click me</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function displayResult(selTag)
{
var x=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = x;
}
```

I know it's not working because of the hyphen between "doesnt-work"

I need to use hyphen as it's automatically created by my application and I don't have any control over it.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Post your code in the question, and your code is wrong on a couple of levels.

Comment: Looks to be an empty fiddle. How come you ppl can see it and I can't? :(

Comment: For one thing, "doesnt-work" is a string, and needs to be quoted if you're going to use it as an argument. Second, what Eric said.

Comment: @DaveNewton Empty for me too, but for some reason I can see stuff in the result window? Bizarre

Answer (score 2):

You are relying on a BAD part of JavaScript. You should not use an elements ID and have the browser hook it up automatically. Use getElementById like you do when you are setting the value.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="displayResult('doesnt-work')">Click
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayResult (selId) {
    var selTag = document.getElementById(selId);
    var x=selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = x;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the answer! I was still trying to edit my question as stackoverflow gave me some error on posting links etc. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is not the problem. You have to pass the id as string to the function:

```
<button onclick="displayResult('doesnt-work')">Click me</button>
```

To get the selected text:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById(selTag);
var x=selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the id as a string, not the object itself;

```
<button onclick="displayResult('doesnt-work')">Click me</button>
```

Then resolve that to an object in the function

```
function displayResult(id)
{
var selTag = document.getElementById(id);
var x = selTag.options[selTag.selectedIndex].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `document.getElementById` instead:

```
<button onclick="displayResult(document.getElementById('doesnt-work'))">Click me</button>
```